# mobile device not detecting media stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am rather new to responsive websites and though I have built a few responsive sites previously that worked fine, for some reason I am having trouble with a current site. When viewed on a laptop or desktop the break points work well when adjusting the browser size, however when viewed on a mobile device it just loads the full size and fits it to the screen width ignoring the media specific stylesheets. As I said I have used this method in the past and haven't had any issues so am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have seen similar issues in forums but haven't had any luck with the solutions provided.

The URL i am working off is www.evolvecollaboration.com/test/index.html and the code from my  is below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/myer_reset.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/structure.css" />  

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:800px)" href="_css/structure_tablet.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px)" href="_css/structure_mobile.css" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, user2824486.

Answer (score 0):

Try these on for size.  I use them for my media queries.

**Phone:**
only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)

**Tablet:**
only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)

**Retina:**
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i have since discovered the issue was not within the code itself, but in how the server was interpreting domain masking.